# Is it possible to break out and reuse layers from an already-trained sequential model?

Tags: keras, autoencoder

I'm fairly new to Keras but have been experimenting with an autoencoder in Keras to explore the underlying dimensionality of a large data set.  A simplified version, omitting imports, activation functions, etc., is shown here:

```
input_dim = 2000
hidden_dim = 300
encoding_dim = 50
output_dim = input_dim

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(input_dim,))
hidden1 = layers.Dense(hidden_dim)(inputs)
encoded = layers.Dense(encoding_dim)(hidden1)
hidden2 = layers.Dense(hidden_dim)(encoded)
decoded = layers.Dense(output_dim)(hidden2)
mymodel = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=decoded)
```

With some effort, I succeeded in training the above model, in that it does a decent job of reproducing the outputs at the inputs.  But I belatedly realized that I'd like to look at what's passing through the bottleneck and how it influences the final output.

My question: is it possible to retroactively break out the trained encoder and decoder sections of the model and call them separately, or do I need to set it up that way from the beginning and restart the training from scratch?

Comment: what do you want to look at exactly? The activations for a given input?

Comment: Among other things, I might like to use the outputs of the encoder as possible inputs to an algorithm (DL or not) for estimating other related variables.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can get the output of the encoder for each input is to create a new NN up to that layer. You can use the [get_weights](https://keras.io/api/layers/base_layer/#get_weights-method) and [set_weights](https://keras.io/api/layers/base_layer/#set_weights-method) methods to get the weights from the trained model and set the weights of the new intermediary model. For example:

```py
int_model = keras.Sequential()

for l in range(encoder_layer + 1):
    int_layer = mymodel.layers[l]
    int_model.add(Dense(
        int_layer.output_shape[1],
        input_dim=int_layer.input_shape[1],
        activation=int_layer.activation)
    )
    int_model.layers[l].set_weights(int_layer.get_weights())
int_model.compile(loss=mymodel.loss)
```

then you can run `int_model.predict()` for all your input and that output will be the encoder layer.

Comment: This looks promising. So the compile() step doesn't reinitialize the weights?  Is it a good idea in any case to set trainable=False?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me yet, though I'm working through some possible fixes. Does the Input layer need to be treated differently? And should I the index references `[1]` applied to `input_shape` and `output_shape` be `[0]`

Comment: it does not reinitialize the weights - layers are responsible for initialization (https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/). I have not used trainable=false in practice before but that sounds reasonable to me - especially for ease of debugging

Comment: input and output shape indexes are `[1]` not `[l]`

Comment: Disregard my question about `[0]` vs. `[1]` -- can't edit the original comment now.